# Update php key debian/ubuntu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, apt-key

How I can renew `php key` in `apt` ? the one I'm using is almost expired.

I've tried to use `https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg` but it will also expire on `2021-03-17`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The gpg key expire in `2021-03-17`.

The gpg key is still valid until `2021-03-17`, the gpg key will be renewed by the debian maintainer Ondřej Surý. Once done you will be invited to update the gpg key. A possible way to do this:

```
sudo curl -sSL -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

Comment: You were right, key was updated before getting expired, thank you for your help.